# Identifying tensors with functions in $C^*$ -algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

We know the result $C(Y,C(X)) \cong C(X)\otimes C(Y)$, I don't able to construct the isomorphism mapping that by starting  an arbitrary function $f$ from $C(X,Y)$, how to get tensor element in $C(X\otimes Y)$, Please help if anybody knows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality as stated makes no sense: first, because $X\otimes Y$ is not defined for topological spaces (the tensor product is defined on vector spaces); second, because if we replace it with $C(X\times Y)$, it is not true: you would have $C([0,1])=C([0,1],\mathbb C)\simeq C([0,1]\times \mathbb C)$, which is false ($C(X)\simeq C(Z)$ implies $X$ and $Z$ are homeomorphic).

The equality that holds is $$ C(X\times Y)\simeq C(X)\otimes C(Y).$$ To write the isomorphism, denote by $f\times g$ the function $(x,y)\longmapsto f(x)g(y)$. The set 
$$
E=\operatorname{span}\{f\times g:\ f\in C(X),\ g\in C(Y)\}
$$
is dense in $C(X\times Y)$; this is seen by Stone-Weierstrass, since $E$ is a $*$-algebra, contains the identity, and separates points. So we may define a linear map $\alpha:E\to C(X)\otimes C(Y)$ by $$ \alpha(f\times g)=f\otimes g.$$It is not hard to see that $\alpha$ is a $*$-homomorphism.

Next, one proves that $\alpha$ is isometric. This requires one to look at the underlying Hilbert space, since it is needed to express the norm in $C(X)\otimes C(Y)$ explicitly. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2778081/22857) for details.

Once you know that $\alpha$ is isometric, it is defined in $C(X\times Y)$, and being an isometry with dense range, it is onto. Thus $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I am sorry, my intention was $C(Y,C(X)) \cong C(X) \otimes C(Y)$ and I want exact map from from the first space to tensors, beginning with a function how will you give map to tensor

Comment: It is easy to map $f\otimes g$ to the function $y\longmapsto g(y)\,f$.

Comment: What about reverse map?@Martin that I am looking for.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can get that.

Comment: Yeah I tried but could not able to do it for many days.